# How to use 100% div height with auto height of wrapper?

Tags: css, html, height

Hello Stackoverflow people! My problem is that I've set the height of a div to 100% and it is ignoring it. Now I've found out that you can't use 100% height if the parent's height is set to auto. I have done this as I want the wrapper to fit to the contents. Solutions for this apparently are to set  and  to heights of 100% as well. This does absolutely nothing for me. Some also suggest using position:absolute, which also doesn't work (neither does relative). Here's my code:

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>link1</li>
<li>link2</li>
<li>link3</li>
<li>link4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
height:auto;
overflow:auto;
}

#menu {
float:left;
width:276px;
height:100%;
background-color:#000000;
position:relative;
}
```

There's also a drop down menu on the last link, however I have tried removing this and it had no effect. There is nothing under the menu and I just want it to fill the space available. Is there a way to do that rather than use a percentage of the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Your menu is dependent on your wrapper

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

[image: Your Webpage]

Do this for HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>link1</li>
<li>link2</li>
<li>link3</li>
<li>link4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
margin:0;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}

#menu {
float:left;
width:276px;
height:100%;
background-color:#1c48db;
position:relative;
}

li{
height: 25%
}
```

It probably isn't the best approach for scaling. But this is as far as I can help with the information you've given.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had before auto and it literally messes everything up. It gives me scroll bars along the wrapper (as if it becomes an iframe), messes up the widths of everything so it all goes on top of each other. It does seem to make the menu go the right height, but as I said does something mad to the width so all the links disappear and due to the content now being underneath the menu it is no longer the size of the wrapper. You might be onto something here though, I'll have a play around with this.

Comment: Alright the issues with widths was caused by the scroll bars appearing so simply making the width a few pixels bigger fixed that. What setting the wrapper to 100% does is make it bigger, but not actually fill the available space. It's just the height of my browser window.

Comment: @28Ostriches What exactly is the problem? What space are you trying to fill? Horizontal, vertical? It would help if you say exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: There's a menu on the left of the page with only a logo above it and an empty space underneath. I want the menu to fill the available empty space without setting a pixel height to it (because I need it to fit to the page like the wrapper is).

Comment: @28Ostriches Set the padding of your html and body to 0. And set the margin of your wrapper to 0. No auto

Comment: No change except the wrapper has moved over to the left rather than the centre.

Comment: @28Ostriches Have a look at my edited answer and let me know how this differs from what you want.

Comment: That appears to be exactly what I want although without the spacing between the links - is this a requirement?

Comment: Texts/Font size can only be increased using the `font-size:` property in CSS. Is it possible to stretch the text within your `<li></li>` tag to fill up the space vertically? Absolutely not.

Comment: Sorry for the weight I went to bed as it was 5:00 AM. I don't want to stretch the text, I want to stretch the div so it fills the vertical space. It looks like you've done that above except the text has stretched with it. How did you do the above? Or are you saying it is impossible to stretch a div to fill vertical space?

Comment: @28Ostriches The div is actually stretched to fill the space. Hence the reason why the entire vertical space is blue. That's the background color for the div.

Comment: @28Ostriches Look at my edited answer for the full code. I would advice you pay more attention to the hierarchy of html elements and understand the [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: I'm afraid this solution won't work as it is just making everything the height of the browser window. I think I'll just change the design of the website and have the empty space under there. I suppose I would have to do this anyway for longer webpages. Thanks for your time anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `#menu` inside of `#wrapper`.  Wrapper is set to auto, and `#menu` is set to 100% of `#wrapper`.  You'll need to set a height to `#wrapper`.

Comment: Thanks, I know, but surely there's a way to have a wrapper that fits the content and still be able to use percentage heights? Something like height:fill would be great! Any Javascript I could use? I tried getting the height of the wrapper and setting it as that, but instead of getting the pixels it just got the auto. Any way of getting the pixels?

Comment: just set your wrapper to be 100%, or whatever percent size you want the over all thing to be.

Comment: With <html> height as 100%, <body> height as 100% and #wrapper height as 100% it essentially makes all of them the height of my browser space.